# MAC npm install issue with gyp

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-sqlite3, hummus.js

I was trying to install the npm, but I keep getting this error that I think is related to the hummus module:

```
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/abcd/Desktop/project/project_l_api/node_modules/hummus
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.8.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.1 found at "/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/abcd/Desktop/project/project_l_api/node_modules/hummus/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/abcd/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.8.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/abcd/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.8.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/abcd/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.8.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/abcd/Desktop/project/project_l_api/node_modules/hummus',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp: Undefined variable module_name in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.8.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/abcd/Desktop/project/project_l_api/node_modules/hummus
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

Also noticed that sometimes the error message indicates the issue with sqlite3 instead of hummus.

Could not get an exact clue to start, I tried to reinstall the npm and the gyp but the problem still persists.

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @RaideR Not yet.. I think there might be some issues related to the Python 2.7.14 vs Python 3.9.1, but I haven't find any clues yet.

Comment: what worked for me: deleting `node_modules` folder, `npm update` and `npm install` afterwards

Comment: It work with me as well!!!

Comment: Also, this worked for me: `npm update --force` and then `npm install`

Answer (score 5):

run `npm update` and `npm install` after.
it worked for me.